# How model class is accessed from controllers?

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP 2.x

2 lines inside AppController in someone else's code I'm trying to understand:

```
 // set the Session data as static values, in the model
    if(isset($this->{$this->modelClass}) && method_exists($this->{$this->modelClass}, 'setSessionInfo'))
                $this->{$this->modelClass}->setSessionInfo($this->Session->read());
```

What $this->{$this->modelClass} will return ? Apparently it refers to AppModel class, but the property modelClass is not set anywhere in AppController or the entire application. Notation '$this->modelClass' is used almost in every controller of the application. Given that modelClass is not part of CakePHP reserved variables how come the code works ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Refer to the source

[modelClass](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L268-L276) is a standard controller class property, which is [set automatically based on the controller class name](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L327). Internally it is used to know the [default model name](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L728-L730) for class loading.

Referring to `modelClass` in the app controller is a relatively common technique to permit inherited code to know and use the main model name for a given controller. Therefore code like this in the app controller:

```
$this->{$this->modelClass}->
```

Would be interpreted like this when executed by a users controller:

```
$this->User->
```

Or this by a products controller:

```
$this->Product->
```

etc.

> `$this->modelClass` is used almost in every controller of the application

That's *not* common; since for a given controller the modelClass to refer to does not change. Using the class property instead of the model name just adds some indirection - probably in your interest to remove this usage in specific controllers.